# How can I make this code await my other code from finishing?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

In my code, it would seem that because of the way my code runs, the code is glitching. I believe that because some of my code is being run while the first part of my code is also being run, it begins to mess with how the animation plays. I may be vague so if you don't understnd I will answer a question. Also if you could help me make it work better that would also be amazing. 
Note: all words in all caps are information that has been taken off to protect privacy. Also, some images are downloaded and cannot be dislayed, therefor please just click on where it says view important message! Thank you all so much! I would like to do this in pure JS, CSS, and HTML. Also, to understand better I suggest using fullscreen!

```js
function showImportantMessage() {
  const element1 = document.querySelector('.importantMessage');
  
  const element2 = document.querySelector('.importantButton');
  

  

  var x = document.getElementById("importantMessage");
  var y = document.getElementById("importantButton");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    
    
    if(element1.classList.contains('animate__animated', 'animate__backOutDown' == true)){
      element1.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__backOutDown');
      if(element1.classList.contains('animate__animated', 'animate__backInUp')){
        element2.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__backInUp');
      }
    }
    element1.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__backInUp');
    element2.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__backOutDown');

  y.style.display = "none";
    
  } else {
    y.style.display = "block";

    if(element1.classList.contains('animate__animated', 'animate__backInUp' == true)){
      element1.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__backInUp');
      if(element1.classList.contains('animate__animated', 'animate__backOutDown')){
        element2.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__backOutDown');
      }
    }
    element1.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__backOutDown');
    element2.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__backInUp');

    x.style.display = "none";
    

  }
  var y = document.getElementById("importantMessage");
  
  y.classList.add('animate_bigger');
  
  
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color:white;
  
}
.center{
  text-align: center;
  
}
.w3-theme {
background-color: #477d72;
}
.w3-theme-text {
background-color: #549688;
}
div.a {
  text-indent: 50px;
}
div.b {
  font-size: 60px;
}
button {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
}
button:hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
  
  //font-weight: 800;
  background-color: blue;
  //color: crimson;
}
.margin {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-left: 45px;
}
.buttonSelector {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 150px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  
}

.home {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.imgOfNAME {
  background-color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 45px;
}
.importantMessage {
  width: 700px;
}
.animate_bigger{
  
}

.importantButton{
  animation: all ease-in-out;
}
.point {
  float: right;
}

.w3-theme {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
.w3-themeTwo {color:#000 !important; background-color:#c2c2c2 !important}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>TITLE</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="faviconStepTWO.png"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      
      <div class="buttonSelector">
  <button class="w3-bar-item home" onClick="BacktoHome()">Home</button>
  
  
  <img class="imgOfNAME"  src="">
  <!---<button class="w3-bar-item" onClick="OpenParents()"> Parents </button>--->



      </header>
      </div>
      
      <div class="margin">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
   
  <h1 class='center'>TITLE</h1>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<img class="imgOfNAME point importantButton" id="importantButton" onclick="showImportantMessage()" width="70px" src="exclamtionMarkONE.png" title="View important message">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<center>
<div id="importantMessage" class="importantMessage">
  <div class="w3-border">
    <br>
    <img width="70px" class="importantPic" src="pointONE.png">
    
   
  <h3><b>Important message!</b></h3>
  <p>DATE</p>
  <p>Dear NAME,
<br>
<br>
<p>INFO</p>
<br>
<button class="w3-button  w3-themeTwo w3-round w3-hover w3-hover-theme w3-hover-theme" id="importantButton" onclick="showImportantMessage()" style="width: 115px; height: 50px;">OK, got it.</button>
<br>
<br>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</center>
  <script>


  var 
x = document.getElementById("importantMessage");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "none";
}</script>


  </body>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: This is so vage that I don't even know where to start. What exactly seems to be the problem? What issues are you encountering? Explain what you want your code to do and what it does now that you don't want it to do. If you just need to wait untill all is rendered, simply add document.ready and if it is somekinda hidden code that is running using Async/Await and Promises then you need to post that code!

Comment: Ok. So It would seem that when the animation startes that opens up the important message, there shiould also be an animation of the button that opens it leaving. The problem is I have to have the veiw the important message button disapeer or else you can scroll down to seel it. Then, when you click OK,got it the message instantly disapeers instead of the code that makes it disapeer waiting. I was hoping there was a way to make them only disapeer after the animation runs its course. Is that any less vague?

Comment: What I want the code to do is after you press the image that says view important message, the button has an animation where it leaves the page and then disapeers. While that is happening I want the message to apeer below the page, and have an animation bring it up. Then when the ok button is pressed it is the opposite, the message goes down and then disapeers, while the image re-apeers and goes up. If they don't disapeer after the animation scrolling down shows both the message and the image. I am sorry I was so vague earlier. I was extremly tired and I didn't explain my problem well enough.

Comment: Last thing because I keep running out of room: I am using animate.css for the animations and for some reason the animation for the view the message image is not working.